# Beginner Java Applet -- Cannot get sound file to playback

Tags: java, audio, applet, awt, bluej

I am working on a beginner java project, and I want a sound to play right when you open the java applet. I have put an .au file in "C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueJ" -- this is where the bluej exe is (I figure that is the correct location for the file the way I call it in my code).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class guitarGame extends Applet implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
AudioClip brainStew; 
Timer timer = new Timer (1000, this);

public void init(){
    brainStew = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "green day - brain stew.au");
    brainStew.play();

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ae){}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ae){

    repaint();
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ae){}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae){}
public void paint (Graphics g)
{   
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have put an .au file in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueJ"` -- this is where the bluej exe is (I figure that is the correct location for the file the way I call it in my code).

You figured wrong.  Your 'program files' directory is not accessible to a server providing the applet page nor therefor the applet.

```
getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "green day - brain stew.au");
```

That will lead to the JVM looking for the resource in the ***same directory as the HTML.***

While the method call might properly URL encode space characters, it might not as well, so this will be more reliable.

```
getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "green%20day%20-%20brain%20stew.au");
```

Comment: I am running this applet straight from bluej I am not uploading it online (why I thought I could call the audio file the way I did) but nevertheless I changed the code, and still no audio file plays when running the applet.

Comment: *"I am running this applet straight from bluej"*  Then you will either need to a) figure out what BlueJ is setting as the 'root' of the app. or b) Stop using BlueJ for testing applets and instead use some simple HTML & applet viewer. -- Since I don't support BlueJ and few other people reply to applet questions, I recommend strategy (b).

Comment: I took your advice and found the root of bluej and put my audio file there and it worked. Thank you!